# Ideal wait time to flag answer as comment

Tags: discussion, flags, low-quality-posts, fastest-gun, grace-period

Sometimes when trivial questions are asked, you notice a rush of answers.

At the beginning most answers are one line, clearly belonging to the comments section, but if you wait you will see those answers being edited and at the end become full answers.

But not all the answers get edited meaning that some one line answers will remain. Those should be flagged as comments.

My question is what is the ideal wait time to start flagging such answers as comments?

Why people rush to put their answers?

Isn't it better to write the full answer before submitting it?

Comment: People rush to get the early upvotes.

Comment: I see. Thanks!  An upvote timer would not be a bad idea.

Comment: @gnat, Although both of the questions relate the same problem, I am more curious about to know what is the ideal waiting time, which the other question does not answer. What kind of edits you propose to salvage this question?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194476/someone-flagged-my-question-as-already-answered-but-its-not Per my experience, ideal waiting time depends on whether one favors safety over productivity. For the former, ideal waiting time is _about two weeks_, for the latter it's _between 0.3 and 30 seconds_

Comment: related: [Fastest gun in the west](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem)